# ESXI Linux Vm high memory usage but no process is using it

Tags: vmware-esxi, centos7, memory

am facing a serious problem in our company server, we have Centos 7 machine on ESXI 7.0 with 26 GB of RAM, every week I have to reboot the VM to avoid full memory usage.

in the mean time I have 13 GB RAM Usage, but by summing all the ram usage of the process I got only 6 GB, here's the output of free -mh:
[image: free -mh]

and "vmware-toolbox-cmd stat balloon = 0 MB"